# check whether a user input is integer. If not, repeat again

Tags: python-3.x, input

This is my current attempt

```
quantity = int(input("How many do you want?? "))
while (quantity < 1 or isinstance(quantity, int) == False):
    print("Error! Please enter a valid quantity value :)")
    quantity = int(input("How many do you want?? "))
```

I've tried to repalce the **==** with **is**, but both return the following error

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'a'
```

What should I do here?